# How to reshape a matrix with identical column and row values?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am working on Matlab and I have a 16x16 matrix where the column values are equal to the row values [matrix of nucleotide substitutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OSW3.jpg)

I would like to reshape it so I have only 1 row containing only the unique values (in other words, I would like a row with:

7816 0 ....6432 0 ....8148 20.....

I tried B = reshape(matrix,1,[]); and it works but unfortunately it is giving me also the non-unique values (it is basically taking every row and pasting it just next to the previous one).

Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Is the output matrix supposed to have some kind of order? Look at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html if order is not important.

Comment: Not really as long as it is one row only. I read the unique but some of the values are the same (e.g. 0's) but not neccessarily non-unique. The output should be one row with 136 values.

Comment: I do not understand the output you are expecting. For a small example like `magic(4)+magic(4).'`, what output do you expect?

Comment: Thanks ...32 7 12 17 22 17 22 17 12 27 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a symmetric input matrix `A`:

```
>> A = randi(30, 5)
A =

    9   13   19   23    8
   13    4    5   14   19
   16   25   13   11   27
   12    3   20   25   11
    1   12    9   20   27

>> A = A + A.'
A =

   18   26   35   35    9
   26    8   30   17   31
   35   30   26   31   36
   35   17   31   50   31
    9   31   36   31   54

>> A(A < 10) = 0
A =

   18   26   35   35    0
   26    0   30   17   31
   35   30   26   31   36
   35   17   31   50   31
    0   31   36   31   54
```

You can extract the lower triangular portion and turn it into a vector like so:

```
>> B = A(find(tril(ones(size(A))))).'
B =

   18   26   35   35    0    0   30   17   31   26   31   36   50   31   54
```

Notice that this skips the `26` in the second column, the `35, 30` in the second column, and so on.

This takes the lower triangular portion of a matrix of 1's the same size as A and finds the indices of all of the 1 values. (That gets around the 0 values in the original matrix.) Then it uses the locations of the 1's returned by `find` to index into the original matrix `A`. Transpose to make it a row vector.

Comment: +1 for understanding the question ;). Was searching the documentation for 20 minutes because I thought there is a built-in to do this, just to realize `squareform` can't be used here.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it was a bit confusing at first, but the key was wanting the unique values of a symmetric matrix. `squareform` would have worked, but it doesn't give you the diagonal as the distance from one point to itself is generally not very interesting. ;)

Comment: @Daniel Oh wait, `squareform` goes the other way, doesn't it? I should really read the documentation more often. :P

Comment: Equivalently: `B = A(bsxfun(@ge, (1:size(A,1)).', 1:size(A,2))).'`